# Define custom string function in OData4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, odata

I'm trying to implement a custom function for OData which should convert `string -> string`. But all sources in the internet including MS docs are very unclear about how can it be done.

Consider following registration:

```
private static ODataConventionModelBuilder AddOrder(this ODataConventionModelBuilder builder)
{
    var entity = builder.EntitySet<Order>(typeof(Order).Name.ToLower());
    entity.EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    var function = entity.EntityType.Function("ToLower2");
    function.IsComposable = true;
    function.SupportedInFilter = true;
    function.Parameter<string>("s");
    function.Returns<string>();
    return builder;
}
```

Here is an OData controller:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("order")]
public sealed class OrdersODataController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.True)]
    [ODataRoute]
    public IQueryable<Order> Get()
    {
        return TestHelper.GetMyQueryable():
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string ToLower2(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Now when calling it:

```
curl 'http://localhost:10100/api/odata/order?$filter=((contains(Default.ToLower2(SomeField),+%27gdgdg%27))&$select=Id&skip=0&$top=5'
```

The response is:

> "message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'Default.ToLower2' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."

Is it possible to implement a custom function like this?

Comment: `MS docs are very unclear about how can it be done.` that's generous. Too generous. You'll have to check the sample projects in the [AspNetoCoreOData](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/master/sample/ODataRoutingSample) repo to start making any sense.  In [this bound function](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/master/sample/ODataRoutingSample/Models/EdmModelBuilder.cs#L20) for example, `.Collection.Function("GetWholeSalary")` says the `GetWholeSalary` function is retrieved through the entity.

Comment: The [actual method](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/master/sample/ODataRoutingSample/Controllers/ProductsController.cs#L135) is almost the same as the one you posted

Comment: Thanks for comments, I've tried it but it didn't help me so I came with my own solution. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I've tried everything docs and examples was saying but it didn't work to me.

I ended up debugging and checking how OData determines which function should be called. Then I've checked APIs that allowed me to register required callbacks. This is what I've ended with:

1. Declare static class with methods that should be registered:

   ```
   public static class CustomFunctions
   {
       public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(string text, string toFind) => 
           throw ShouldBeTranslatedException;

       private static Exception ShouldBeTranslatedException => 
           new Exception("Should be translated to MongoDb/SQL");
   }
   ```
2. Register it to OData:

   ```
   private static void RegisterCustomFunction(string functionName)
   {
       var methodInfo = typeof(CustomFunctions).GetMethod(functionName)!;
       var returnType = TypeToReference(methodInfo.ReturnType);
       var args = methodInfo.GetParameters()
           .Select(x => TypeToReference(x.ParameterType))
           .ToArray();
       var signature = new FunctionSignatureWithReturnType(returnType, args);
       ODataUriFunctions.AddCustomUriFunction(functionName, signature, methodInfo);
   }

   private static IEdmTypeReference TypeToReference(Type type)
   {
       var primitiveTypeKind = EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetPrimitiveTypeKind(type.Name);
       var isNullable = type.IsClass || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
       return new EdmPrimitiveTypeReference(
           EdmCoreModel.Instance.GetPrimitiveType(primitiveTypeKind),
           isNullable);
   }

   ...

   RegisterCustomFunction(nameof(CustomFunctions.ContainsIgnoreCase));
   ```
3. Now OData will be happy with it and you just need to write your translation code to convert it into SQL (or mongo query in my case)

Comment: Your third bullet there is a bit foggy to me. Do you just mean "implement the logic instead of throwing `ShouldBeTranslatedException`"? Since those methods are not based on `Expression`, I wonder how it is able to translate them. If that's not what you meant, can you complement your answer here with a bit more details on how to do the SQL conversion part?

Comment: In my case I was translating this into mongodb, so I had a fork of mongodb.driver which was interpreting this AST as required. E.G. you can add another `if` here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/93614cccfa52d34a5807477df614aee6a2beb0a6/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Linq3Implementation/Translators/ExpressionToAggregationExpressionTranslators/MethodTranslators/ToLowerOrToUpperMethodToAggregationExpressionTranslator.cs#L25

Comment: Very interesting! How exactly do you link that translation method with OData though? Do you have to register it somewhere? It would be really nice if you could provide a full working example here in the answer so that others could follow.

Comment: Well here is my old PR that among others added support for `Contains` function. It works similar for any custom functions you can register: https://github.com/Pzixel/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/1/files#diff-8fa3bc2c6721235e29fe0189ef7a13026326ad03be6be4dabc34ac45c2ea2c41R1355

Comment: The idea is you have this functions stub in order to have expression that invokes them. They are not supposed to be called though, they should be translated. It's quite similar to `SqlMethods.Like` and functions alike

Comment: Thanks for the link. At first glance it seems like the third bullet on your answer is fairly straightforward and "left as an exercise to the reader" but it appears to be a fairly complex part of this. I still think it would be beneficial to have the whole process documented in your answer however. As it stands, it is practically impossible for someone who wants a custom OData function to just follow your answer and be able to make that work.

Comment: I'll try reaching my old coworkers to share some code pieces that are needed and write some simple example. But the main idea here is that first two bullets are about "how to make OData happy with custom functions". The third bullet is about implementing correct translaction logics and it's very specific to engine you are using

Comment: Okay so I uploaded a new PR that includes all fixes I made to make OData work with Mongodb. Here you can see CustomFunctions declared and used: https://github.com/Pzixel/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/1/files#diff-8fa3bc2c6721235e29fe0189ef7a13026326ad03be6be4dabc34ac45c2ea2c41R1232

This is gist from the code that registers and uses all this:
https://gist.github.com/Pzixel/cf09ca4f360356d8749a9fe2049d3169